# SharePoint open ribbon on page load

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint-2010, schema

The problem I'm facing is getting the ribbon to open up automatically when I load a page, say I click on the 'Customer Info' link in the quick launch menu, I'd like the ribbon for the Customer Info page to appear upon loading the page.

We have some javascript that does this on custom pages with webparts, seen below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    WpClick({
        srcElement: $(".s4-wpcell").get(0),
        target: $(".s4-wpcell").get(0)
    });

    $(".item-select").click(function () {
        RefreshCommandUI();
    });
});
```

The pages I'm trying to do it on are just your run of the mill SharePoint pages with the 'add new item' link etc. Is there a way to do this through the schema file? Or is there some way to put the javascript code above into the schema file so it does this?

I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options.

1. If you need the ribbon to always be open on page load within that site then put the javascript in your masterpage for that site (this may mean you need to create a custom masterpage deriving from the one you have now that includes this javascript)
2. If this is on a small number of pages (and the number isn't going to grow in the future) then I would recommend just putting the javascript in a content editor webpart. This can be hard to maintain if you expect this requirement for a lot of newly created pages on the site.
3. If you need to have the ribbon loaded for a number of page types look into creating custom page layouts for these page types (if you haven't already) and add the javascript to the page layouts you need it for. This may not be a good option if you are working with a bunch of pages that are already created using the out of the box templates as you would need to do some sort of migration to the new page layout.